# Why is D3.js data only available to child nodes when enter() is chained, not invoked separately

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-binding

I'm trying to follow what Mike Bostock [seems to indicate is a best practice](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218), namely assigning your `selectAll()` to a variable and then separating out the update, the `enter()` and the `exit()`, but I'm noticing a discrepancy in V4 that I can't explain.

Consider the following working code:

```
// Bind an array of users to the #users div
        var userNodes = d3.select("#users").selectAll("li")
            .data(d3.values(users))

            // Add LIs for any new users
            .enter()
                .append("li");

        var userMessageGraph = userNodes.selectAll("span")
            .data(function(d){ return [d.name]; })
            .enter().append("span")
                .text(function(d){ return d; });
```

Which creates an empty LI and then appends a SPAN inside it with the user name. (By the way, if this is all I wanted I'm sure there's a better way, but this is just a reduction of something else to illustrate my point. Bear with me if you will.)

Now I try to adapt it to my interpretatioin of said best practice by running the `enter()` against the stored variable, and the child elements lose their link to the parent data. I get a list of empty LIs.

```
// Bind an array of users to the #users div
        var userNodes = d3.select("#users").selectAll("li")
            .data(d3.values(users));

        // Add LIs for any new users
        userNodes.enter()
            .append("li");

        var userMessageGraph = userNodes.selectAll("span")
            .data(function(d){ return [d.name]; })
            .enter().append("span")
                .text(function(d){ return d; });
```

### Update 1

Well, after reading [[~Gerardo Furtado]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41072582/467386)'s response, I thought I had it. Clearly I'm missing a fundamental principle here.

Here's my code that attempts to use `merge()` to make sure the data is carried over to the child elements, with no joy:

```
var userNodes = d3.select("#users").selectAll("li")
        .data(d3.values(users));

        // Add LIs for any new users
        userNodes.enter()
            .append("li")
            // New for V4, merge back the original set to get the data
            .merge(userNodes);

        var userMessageGraph = userNodes.selectAll("span")
            .data(function(d){ return [d.name]; })
            .enter().append("span")
                .text(function(d){ return d; });
```

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you're using d3 v4.x. In that case, that's the expected behaviour.

This is what's happening: `userNodes` is the data binding variable:

```
var userNodes = d3.select("#users").selectAll("li")
    .data(d3.values(users));
```

Then, you write:

```
userNodes.enter()
    .append("li");
```

And that's the "enter" selection.

In d3 v3.x that enter selection *magically* modifies your original variable, turning it into this:

```
var userNodes = d3.select("#users").selectAll("li")
    .data(d3.values(users));
    .enter()
    .append("li");
```

However, in d3 v4.x, your original variable remains just a data binding selection:

```
var userNodes = d3.select("#users").selectAll("li")
    .data(d3.values(users));
```

So, if we rewrite your `userMessageGraph` taking into account the chaining, this is what it really is:

```
var userMessageGraph = d3.select("#users")//here userNode starts
    .selectAll("li")
    .data(d3.values(users))//this is where userNode ends
    .selectAll("span")
    .data(function(d){ return [d.name]; })
    .enter().append("span")
    .text(function(d){ return d; });
```

You can see that the "enter" selection for the `<li>`, which is...

```
.enter()
.append("li")
```

...is missing.

**EDIT:** This edit addresses the OP's new code:

```
var userNodes = d3.select("#users").selectAll("li")
    .data(d3.values(users));

// Add LIs for any new users
userNodes.enter()
    .append("li")
    // New for V4, merge back the original set to get the data
    .merge(userNodes);
```

That won't work for a reason: the `merge` function...

> ...returns a new selection merging this selection with the specified other selection. The returned selection has the same number of groups and the same parents as **this** selection. (emphasis mine)

As `userNodes` is an empty selection, this will not work. You can invert the logic:

```
var userNodes = d3.select("#users").selectAll("li")
    .data(d3.values(users));

var userNodesEnter = userNodes.enter()
    .append("li");

var userNodesUpdate = userNodesEnter.merge(userNodes);

var userMessageGraph = userNodesUpdate.selectAll("span")
    .data(function(d) {
        return [d.name];
    })
    .enter().append("span")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d;
    });
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the answer. So does that mean that the old (V3) "general update pattern" is no longer the recommended approach? Is there a V4-revised approach that works better now that the "magic" has been removed?

Comment: The example you linked (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) **does** use v4.x, and it's the recommended approach. Just pay attention to the `merge()` function.

Comment: I'm so sorry I haven't been able to give this my attention lately. I finally got a chance to try your code, and unfortunately it's still yielding no results - the <LI>s remain empty (no SPANs are created). I think there's something else at play here - it seems to be that the data binding is lost on the child elements.